# Solr Indexing using Nutch Crawler

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, nutch

I'm using Apache Nutch-1.13 and solr 6.6.0 versions.

I'm running the following command to crawl the content:

```
bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch urls/seed.txt TestCrawl 2
```

I got this exception:

```
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)

Error running:
  /Users/myedlapalli/documents/nutch-solr-3/apache-nutch-1.13/runtime/local/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch TestCrawl/crawldb -linkdb TestCrawl/linkdb TestCrawl/segments/20171017090519
Failed with exit value 255.
```

And in the logs:

```
2017-10-17 09:36:35,032 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 1/1 documents
2017-10-17 09:36:35,032 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
2017-10-17 09:36:35,161 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 1/1 documents
2017-10-17 09:36:35,161 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Deleting 0 documents
2017-10-17 09:36:35,174 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local193014604_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch: ERROR: [doc=http://www.cmo.com/features/articles/2017/8/21/5-emerging-technologies-rewrite-the-media-and-entertainment-script-.html] unknown field 'sp_type'
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch: ERROR: [doc=http://www.cmo.com/features/articles/2017/8/21/5-emerging-technologies-rewrite-the-media-and-entertainment-script-.html] unknown field 'sp_type'
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.push(SolrIndexWriter.java:210)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.commit(SolrIndexWriter.java:188)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:179)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:117)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-10-17 09:36:36,109 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this cases is usually a good idea to check the logs on the Solr side, but for this particular error. You already have the answer, especially the portion:

```
ERROR: [doc=http://www.cmo.com/features/articles/2017/8/21/5-emerging-technologies-rewrite-the-media-and-entertainment-script-.html] unknown field 'sp_type'
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:576)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:240)
```

Solr, is complaining that you're sending a document (with id `http://www.cmo.com/features/articles/2017/8/21/5`...) with one field that is not defined in the schema: `sp_type`.

You should check what you're sending in that field, or just add the field in the Solr schema.

> Keep in mind that if you have more fields that are not defined in the Solr schema, this error will continue to appear. Is usually a good idea to run the `bin/nutch indexchecker <URL>` command to see what Nutch is going to send to Solr.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i can tell you is to follow the crawling process with bin/nutch over the crawl command. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/nutch/NutchTutorial gives you more details.